# id must be a number conforming to the specified constraints

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

That's the error thrown by class-validator. Here is the code for my dto:

```
export class UpdateEntryBodyDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsNumber()
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    @Validate(IsUniqueEntryTitle)
    title?: string;
}
```

I tried a few more different configurations but I'm getting about the same damn error. I'm totally discombobulated by this error, can't figure out what the hell is wrong with this code,
I do it like it's recommended [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1331) but to no avail...

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is this a DTO for? Query Params? URL Parans? A POST/PATCH/PUT body? What's the payload being sent in?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel it was a `PUT` request, yeah, I've finally figured out the reason why it would not work :D

Answer (score 9):

Ah, I've finally figured it out. I'm using `Insomnia` as my http client and I was sending `Multipart Form` (it used to be the case but no longer is) instead of `Form Url Encoded`. I simply forgot to change the request body type. So perhaps this will be of help if anyone stumbles across something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `enableImplicitConversion` as `true` in your `ValidationPipe`?

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
  transform: true,
  transformOptions: {
    enableImplicitConversion: true, // <- This line here
  },
}));
```

This should also work locally e.g., in a `Controller` or method.